# Hashing String List Elements and Saving to a New List

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to take 100 names, hash each name to 8 bits and save it to a new list. I understand that using 8 bits will most likely result in collisions, I'm trying to see at what rate they will collide and I'm hoping to include this code snippet in my paper.

I believe my logic is okay, it's just syntax that's causing my issues. Any help is appreciated.

```
import hashlib

list = ["Cammy", "Maisha", "Lizette", "Marjorie", "Shaquita", "Rueben", "Fatima", "Maynard",
        "Laurena", "Lauren", "Allyson", "Pearlie", "Bethel", "Daniell", "Laurinda", "Crista",
        "Ching", "Kareen", "Beth", "Stephnie", "Manie", "Kareem", "Titus", "Humberto",
        "Lauretta", "Rob", "Raul", "Damion", "Stephani", "Carin", "Sharla", "Eleonor", "Naida",
        "Ashley", "Rachel", "Graig", "Raymonde", "Shalanda", "Annetta", "Lissette", "Sandi",
        "Alda", "Arlinda", "Ashlee", "Marguerite", "Tammi", "Denisha", "Genie", "Elizbeth",
        "Elvie", "Markus", "Marquitta", "Arla", "Vanda", "Devon", "Meagan", "Taryn", "Lina",
        "Shea", "Leighann", "Janel", "Sanora",  "Harmony", "Concetta", "Dwayne", "Kyla",
        "Evonne", "Mauro", "Deane", "Chester", "Inez", "Tari", "Maribeth", "Ariel", "Elisa",
        "Maurice", "Dung", "Mona", "Hung", "Maximina", "Demarcus", "Jayson", "Jenny", "Duane",
        "Reginia", "Gennie", "Orval", "Venus", "Craig", "Lessie", "Madaline", "Paulina",
        "Aletha", "Gisele", "Sheena", "Devora", "Arcelia", "Ericka", "Colene", "Hildegard"]

newlist = []

for i in list:
    newlist = hash(list[i] % 10**8)

for i in newlist:
    print(i)
```

Comment: `newlist` holds only last hashed value. Can you use `append()`? Also, `list` is reserved for built-in.

Comment: What is the number `10**8` intended to represent in this code? I could understand `2**8` for 8 bits, but `10**8` ?

Comment: @khelwood to make the hashed number 8 bits

Comment: @sudo-potato Bits are binary digits, not decimal digits. I think you mean `2**8`.

Comment: @khelwood You are right, not sure how I missed that.

Comment: You also need parentheses around it `(2**8)`, so that the `**` operator is evaluated before the `%` operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without touching your logic, to make your code work you want to replace these lines:

```py
for i in list:
    newlist = hash(list[i] % 10**8)
```

with

```py
for i in list:
    newlist.append(hash(i) % 10**8)
```

Some clarification:

In Python, you can use `.append()` on any list object to add elements to the end of that list. In this case, you're filling the empty list you initialized above with elements inside a loop. Further, other than in e.g. a classic Java loop, in Python you can iterate over a list directly, such that your `i` refers to a different element of the list each time. Thus, there is no need to try and access the list at a certain index each time. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I understand my mistake.

Comment: How could I not help someone named sudo-potato :)

Comment: @sudo-potato By the way, you're using the inbuilt function `hash()`. This function is available no matter what, so there is no need to `import hashlib`. That is a library that can create hashes using several different algorithms, you can read up on it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html). I don't know which suits you better, it's just a heads up.